# Why is my function outputting a random value, which looks like a memory address?

Tags: ios, sqlite, double, nsnumber

I'm trying to output the value of a latitude and longitude, which I have queried from an sql table. My issue is that when the value is 0.000000 it outputs something along the lines of 1.04480899798659e-276.
I have checked the value of the output above these two line of code:

```
latitudeOutput.text = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[theGPS latitude]] stringValue];
longitudeOutput.text = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[theGPS longitude]] stringValue];
```

and it should definitely be outputting 0.000000 . Does anyone know why this is happening, and anyway I can fix it?

----Added Section----

Why does this if else statement carry straight on through to the else section, despite the latitude and longitude value being equal to 0.000000?

```
if(latitude == @"0.000000" && longitude == @"0.000000"){
    latitudeOutput.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    longitudeOutput.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    latitudeOutput.text = @"Latitude";
    longitudeOutput.text = @"Longitude";
}
else {
    latitudeOutput.text = latitude;
    longitudeOutput.text = longitude;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the latitude and longitude as string? Try this: `latitudeOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [theGPS latitude]];`

Comment: For this kind of comparison you need to use `isEqualToString:` so it will be `[latitude isEqualToString:@"0.000000"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory addresses have format of `0xdeadbeef`.

Your value is a double written in a "variation" of [scientfic notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples_and_other_notations) It is something extremely close to 0.0 [(wolfram alpha visualization)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.04480899798659e-276&dataset=)

This happens because of how computers store floating point values. You can read more [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

To fix your issue, I'd suggest formating the output to include only as much digits after decimal point as you need.

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [theGPS latitude]];
```

This will give you 2 places after decimal point.

Comment: This did work! Is there any chance you can now tell me why this if else statement just carries straight onto the else section? I've added it to the question